# Modifying part of a regex in replaceAll call

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to format a string with a regex as follows:

```
String string = "5.07+12.0+2.14";
string = string.replaceAll("\\.0[^0-9]","");
```

What I think will happen is the string will become:

```
5.07+122.14 //the regex will delete the .0+ next to the 12
```

How can I create the regex so that it deletes **only** the .0 not the + sign?

I would prefer to do **everything in the same call** to "replaceAll"

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: why would 5.07 become 57 since .0 is follow by a digit @CertainPerformance

Comment: Or you can use negative lookahead `\.0(?!\d)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matched characters will be replaced. So, instead of *matching* the non-digit at the end, you can use lookahead, which will perform the desired check but won't consume any characters. Also, the shorthand for a non-digit is `\D`, which is a bit nicer to read than `[^0-9]`:

```
String string = "5.07+12.0+2.14";
string = string.replaceAll("\\.0(?=\\D)","");
```

If you want to replace *all* trailing zeros (for example, replace `5.00` with `5` instead of `50`, which you probably don't want), then repeat the 0 one or more times with `+` to ensure that *all* zeros after the decimal point get replaced:

```
String string = "5.07+12.000+2.14";
string = string.replaceAll("\\.0+(?=\\D)","");
```

If the string never contains *alphabetical or underscore `_` characters* (those and numeric characters count as word characters), then you can make it even prettier with a word boundary instead of a lookahead. A word boundary, as it sounds, will match a position with a word character on one side and a non-word character on the other side, with `\b`:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\.0+\\b","");
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the = sign?

Comment: `(?=` is the syntax for the beginning of a lookahead. it checks that the following pattern matches, but doesn't consume any characters. (End the lookahead like you would end any group, with `)`)

Comment: so it should only replace the first group, Not the lookahead?

Comment: Right - lookahead does not consume any characters, it only ensures that the following pattern matches.

Comment: thanks for the hints. I will test them in netbeans and then upvote your answer.